# Openlayers Select Feature: avoiding the on/off aspect of selecting a feature: want to be able to click, then click again

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, popup

Map here: http://tinyurl.com/potjxlu

I can click an orange icon, popup appears, hit the X button to exit out of the popup.That is OK.

But if I want to bring that popup again for the same point, I have to click it twice, not once.

Also, sometimes the X button in the popup becomes disabled. It's not a consistent error so not sure what's going on there.

Looking at the OL docs for SelectFeature, I thought `highlightOnly` may be the solution but it is not.

The current code for my select feature control:

```
var selector = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([wfs, vectors_origin, vectors_destination], {
            clickout: false,
            toggle: true,
            hover: false,
            autoActivate:true
    });
```

If I just use the default vectors (the little orange circles), what's happening is:

-I'll click the orange circle, the orange circle becomes highlighted with a dark purple: the popup now appears.

-The popup has an X button. I click this to exit out and that aspect works.

-Now at this point: the orange circle is still highlighted the dark purple: in other words it is still selected.

-So what happens is I have to click WITHIN the orange circle (currently highlighted dark purple) to UNSELECT it. Now that dark purple has turned back to the initial orange.

-Now I can click it again and the popup should appear correctly: which it does.

How do I skip this middle step?

Note that my issue is only for points that you want to click again: if I click the Austin, TX feature then the Los Angeles, CA feature, there are no issues with the popups but I want to cut out this middle deselection step as it seems unncessary for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farhatabbas/TtfDe/22/) actually the trick is to unselect feature when user clicks close (red button on popup) to close information popup.

Comment: Fantastic, I was missing this `selectControl.unselect(feature)` . Line 50 from the fiddle. Thank you for your reply.